# cordova build android fails on :app:mergeReleaseResources step with "Daemon startup failed" message

Tags: android, linux, cordova, gradle

I'm using [this fork of the setup-cordova GitHub action](https://github.com/RedstonePfalz/setup-cordova) to build a cordova project.  It used to work a few months ago, but now the `cordova build android` step fails with the message "Daemon startup failed", and there are many error messages saying "symbol not found".  The logs are below.  How can I fix this error?

```
cordova version: 
11.1.0
Installed platforms:
  
Available platforms: 
  android ^10.1.1
  browser ^6.0.0
  electron ^3.0.0
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^10.1.1
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.someapp.someapp
    Name: Some App
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-30
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Android project created with cordova-android@10.1.2
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk-linux (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk-linux

Welcome to Gradle 7.5.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Support for Java 18
 - Support for building with Groovy 4
 - Much more responsive continuous builds
 - Improved diagnostics for dependency resolution

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :wrapper

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: Error relocating /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a15c26061a26a3ff1f644e99469209bc/transformed/aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux/aapt2: __longjmp_chk: symbol not found
AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: Error relocating /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a15c26061a26a3ff1f644e99469209bc/transformed/aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux/aapt2: __isnan: symbol not found
AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: Error relocating /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a15c26061a26a3ff1f644e99469209bc/transformed/aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux/aapt2: __isnanf: symbol not found
AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: Error relocating /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a15c26061a26a3ff1f644e99469209bc/transformed/aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux/aapt2: __vsnprintf_chk: symbol not found
AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: Error relocating /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a15c26061a26a3ff1f644e99469209bc/transformed/aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux/aapt2: __vfprintf_chk: symbol not found
AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: Error relocating /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a15c26061a26a3ff1f644e99469209bc/transformed/aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux/aapt2: __memmove_chk: symbol not found
AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: Error relocating /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a15c26061a26a3ff1f644e99469209bc/transformed/aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux/aapt2: __vasprintf_chk: symbol not found
AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: Error relocating /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a15c26061a26a3ff1f644e99469209bc/transformed/aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux/aapt2: strtoll_l: symbol not found
AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: Error relocating /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a15c26061a26a3ff1f644e99469209bc/transformed/aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux/aapt2: strtoull_l: symbol not found
AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: Error relocating /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a15c26061a26a3ff1f644e99469209bc/transformed/aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux/aapt2: __longjmp_chk: symbol not found
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
> Task :CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
   > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 55s
```

Comment: try reinstalling android studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, [the setup-cordova GitHub action](https://github.com/RedstonePfalz/setup-cordova) is now broken for everyone. You can test this yourself by simply forking the GitHub project and triggering the included “Continuous Integration” workflow (by first activating the workflow and then creating a new dummy commit). The workflow will fail with (basically) the same error that you saw.

The reason why it worked “a few months ago” is probably the following: the Docker container underyling the GitHub action automatically uses the latest Android SDK. The SDK version has most likely changed since you’ve run your last build. The previous version was still compatible with the Alpine-based Docker container but at least the included AAPT2 version from the newer Android SDK Build-Tools does not run anymore on Alpine. “Error relocating […] symbol not found” is a common issue when trying to run more ‘complex’ setups on Alpine; hence my hunch that the SDK seems to have changed since you’ve last used it.

To fix this, I would create my own fork of the GitHub action and use that instead. Here are the rough changes to the `Dockerfile` that could fix it:

- Change the base image to `runmymind/docker-android-sdk:ubuntu-standalone` (as Ubuntu is “the officialy supported Linux distribution for Android SDK builds” ([via](https://github.com/mindrunner/docker-android-sdk/blob/8610b51f0d696d54e720341b8c74cc0440e851ed/README.md))).
- Translate all the `apk` commands to their corresponding `apt` counterparts.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but it looks good to me.  I'm going to accept the answer so that you get the bounty.

Comment: It worked.  For those who are interested, I've got a working version of the action here: https://github.com/rhombicarts/setup-cordova